# Как правильно создать условие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать такое условие, чтобы `title` картинки выводился исключительно в случае, если картинка шириной более, скажем, чем 500 px? И второй вариант условия: если в свойствах картинки отсутствует выравнивание `float`, например `<img src="kartinka.jpg" alt="Альтернативная подсказка" title="Название картинки" style="float:right;">`.

Возможно ли такое в принципе? Благодарю вас за помощь!

```
jQuery(function($) {
    newsImg = $(".news img");
    newsImg.after(function(){
        imgTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        if (imgTitle) return "<div class='img_title'>"+imgTitle+"</div>";
    });
});
```

Comment: как флоат назначается? просто в css? нужено только если флоат не равен ни одному?

Comment: float описывается инлайново?

Comment: Эти 2 условия нужно объединить в одно? Или как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывайте также проверять `img` на такие условия, как:

- наличие атрибута `title`, иначе при соответсвии остальным критериям у вас в `.img_title` будет выводиться `undefined`;
- длина атрибута `title`, иначе при `title=""` у вас будет создаваться пустой `.img_title`.

```js
$(function() {
  newsImg = $(".news img");
  newsImg.after(function() {
    imgTitle = $(this).attr("title");
    if (imgTitle && imgTitle != '' && $(this).width() > 500 && $(this).css('float') == 'none') return "<div class='img_title'>" + imgTitle + "</div>";
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/bmw_m4_coupe_4k_17473.jpg" style="width:400px">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/bmw_m4_coupe_4k_17473.jpg" style="width:600px;float:right">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/bmw_m4_coupe_4k_17473.jpg" style="width:600px">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/bmw_m4_coupe_4k_17473.jpg" title="" style="width:600px">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/bmw_m4_coupe_4k_17473.jpg" title="Соответствует всем условиям" style="width:600px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
    newsImg = $(".news img");
    newsImg.after(function(){
        imgTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        if ($(this).width() > 500 && $(this).css('float') == 'none') return "<div class='img_title'>"+imgTitle+"</div>";
    });
});
```

```css
.news{
    height: 100px;
}
img{
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news"><img title="Нет" style="width:400px">
<img title="Нет" style="width:600px;float:right">
<img title="Пройдет тест" style="width:600px">
</div>
```

Comment: А если title нет, вы все равно будете выводить attr('title')?

Comment: ну в вопросе же не было о тайтле. Да и оно не выводит только тем кто подходит по условию

Comment: @Horchynskyi в вопросе как раз это условие есть

Comment: @LADYX если при таком условии title не будет, то код выведет вам undefined

Comment: чёт я не вижу условия. Там же написанно чтобы тайлт выводился только если блок > 500 и нету флоата